# Doctrine COUNT in subquery with HAVING

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to get a list of user rankings for the leaderboard. I have three tables:

- users (id, username)
- circuits (id, name)
- user_circuits (id, user, circuit, record)

The records are calculated correctly but I always get the **total number of users** instead of the ranking. This is my query:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('
    SELECT
        u.id AS id,
        u.username AS username,
        COALESCE(MAX(c.record), 0) AS record,
        (
            SELECT
                COUNT(DISTINCT u2.id)
            FROM ApplicationSonataUserBundle:User u2
            LEFT JOIN u2.circuits c2
            HAVING COALESCE(MAX(c2.record), 0) > record
        ) AS ranking
    FROM ApplicationSonataUserBundle:User u
    LEFT JOIN u.circuits c
    GROUP BY id, username
    ORDER BY record DESC
');

$leaderboard = $query
    ->setMaxResults($max)
    ->getArrayResult()
;
```

This is the result:

```
UserRepository.php on line 88:
array:20 [
  0 => array:4 [
    "id" => 427
    "username" => "ninety-nine"
    "record" => "99"
    "ranking" => "102"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [
    "id" => 426
    "username" => "ninety-eight"
    "record" => "98"
    "ranking" => "102"
  ]
  2 => array:4 [
    "id" => 425
    "username" => "ninety-seven"
    "record" => "97"
    "ranking" => "102"
  ]
  3 => array:4 [
    "id" => 424
    "username" => "ninety-six"
    "record" => "96"
    "ranking" => "102"
  ]
  4 => array:4 [
    "id" => 423
    "username" => "ninety-five"
    "record" => "95"
    "ranking" => "102"
  ]
]
```

Comment: I guess you miss `GROUP BY` before the `HAVING`

Comment: The problem is that I have nothing to group by because `COUNT(DISTINCT u2.id)` is already an aggregate function. Which fields should I select to use a `GROUP BY`?